# regex match of second line from finding word

Tags: python, regex

I need to find second line after matching "Pass Rate"

```
Lib Cell                                        Pass Rate
--------------------------------               -----------  
ts10300.slqlql.lwlwl.opep.frame                 0.1714
```

I have tried with the regular expression

```
.*Pass Rate\n.*?(?:\n\s(?=\w+\S))
```

but it is not working. See https://regex101.com/r/db9KWj/1

Expected output: `ts10300.slqlql.lwlwl.opep.frame                 0.1714`

Answer (score 2):

This will do: `Pass Rate\n.*\n(.*)\b`

See: https://regex101.com/r/db9KWj/2

I disabled the multiline option `m`

Comment: You might add an explanation why the OP's pattern does not match (The second line does not start with a whitspace char, and the assertion is non consuming)

Answer (score 0):

Group 3 returned by matches from the following pattern meet your use case `(Pass Rate\n)(.*\n)(.*)`.

- `(Pass Rate\n)` - match `Pass Rate\n` (Group 1)
- `(.*\n)` - Matches first line following line ending `Pass Rate` (Group 2)
- `(.*)` - Matches second line following line ending `Pass Rate` (Group 3)

Given the example from your question as `test.txt` and using simple calls to `print()` for illustrative purposes:

```py
import re

filename = "test.txt"

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

match = re.search(r"(Pass Rate\n)(.*\n)(.*)", s)

if match:
    output = match.group(3)
    print(output)
else:
    print(f"No match found in {filename}")
```

Comment: You don't need the multiline flag, as the pattern does not contain an anchor. Instead of using 2 capturing groups, you can use a single capturing group for only the second line that the OP wants. Instead of using the positive lookbehind, you can just use a match instead.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Spot on, thanks for pointing out the shortcomings of my original pattern/answer. Updated based on your feedback and is clearly much cleaner.

Comment: You can still omit the first 2 capturing groups like `Pass Rate\n.*\n(.*)` (Which in that case will be almost the same answer as already posted by Christian Baumann.